# Is the mapping $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} ^2$ given by $(\xi_1,\xi_2) \to (\xi_1,0) $ an open mapping ?Yes/No

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, open-map

Is the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}  ^2$ given  by $(\xi_1,\xi_2) \to (\xi_1,0) $ an open mapping ?Yes/No

**My attempt** : yes ,I think it is open  because  collection of elements of the form $(\xi_1,0)$  is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Let $U\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be open. Suppose  $z\in f(U)$. Then there is $(\xi_1,0)\in U$ with $\xi_1=z$. As $U$ is open, there exists $r>0$ such that $(\xi_1-r,\xi_1+r)\subseteq U$. Conclude that $(z-r,z+r)\subseteq f(U)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(z-r,z+r)$?

Comment: open ball in $\mathbb{R}$  @J.W.Tanner

Comment: then how can you compare it to $f(U)\subseteq \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Im sorry for that  @J.W.Tanner That's my thinking .$\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \implies  f(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \implies f(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Technically $\mathbb R\not\subset \mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Is $]z-r, z+r[\times\{0\}$ an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the thinking behind that?  I know that  $(z-r,z=r) $ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{0\}$  is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @jasmine In the canonical topology on $\mathbb R^n$, a set is called "open" if and only if for every point in that set, you can fit a ball containing that point with strictly positive radius into that set. Is there any ball with positive radius that fits into, say, $]-1,1[\times\{0\}$ around the point $(0,0)$ ? (Try drawing the set $]-1,1[\times\{0\}$ if you want!)

Comment: ok  ,that   means $B(0,\epsilon)=(0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon )$ but $0 \neq 0+\epsilon $.This leads to the contradiction  that contained in  $]-1,1[ \times \{0\}$.Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine No. An open ball in $\mathbb R^2$ (with the canonical metric) around $0$ is given by $$\mathbb B(0,\varepsilon)\overset{\text{Def.}}=\{\mathbf x=(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2\le\varepsilon^2\}.$$ This is *not* the same as $]0-\varepsilon, 0+\varepsilon[$ (which is the open ball around $0$ with radius $\varepsilon$ in one dimension.) For example, note that the ordered pair (not interval!) $(0,\varepsilon/2)$ is always contained as an element in $\mathbb B(0,\varepsilon)$. Is it also contained as an element in any $]z-r,z+r[\times\{0\}$ ?

Comment: ok, balls are bigger than this line. Therefore, not contained as an element  in any $(z-r,z+r) \times \{0\}$ Am  i right ?

Comment: @jasmine Yes, the idea is that you cannot fit an open ball into a line. I would encourage you to try to formalize this idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Then there is $\xi_1 \in U$ with $\xi_1 = z$.

No. $z \in f(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, so $z$ is an ordered pair, not a single number $\xi_1$.

> Conclude that $(z - r, z + r) \subseteq f(U)$.

What does this mean? $(z - r, z + r) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is an ordered pair of numbers, so it doesn't make sense to say it's a subset of $f(U)$.

Do you mean $(z - r, z + r) \in f(U)$? If so, you should prove this by showing there exists $a, b$ such that $f(a, b) = (z - r, z + r)$.

Comment: I think OP means an open interval when writing $(z-r,z+r)$, not an ordered pair .

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Then we still have a problem, since $(z - r, z + r)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$. So it can't be reasonably compared to $f(U)$.

Comment: Yes, I agree! I interpreted $(z-r,z+r)$ in this context as $(z-r,z+r)\times\{0\}$, but indeed that is a formal mistake of the OP.